# How do I 'warn' the Application that I closed the DLL it called?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7

Since I know you guys are exceptional people with awesome talents, maybe someone might be able to help me with this.

This is the situation:
I have an Application that calls a DLL. The catch here is that I'm opening the DLL in a TAdvPanel (it belongs to a TMS library, but I believe it works for the standard Panels too), and it works perfectly fine.

Whenever I close the tab, I can always call the DLL again and recreate its Form, but when I close the Form, the tab where the DLL was stays open, with no content inside of it.

Is there a way for me to "warn" the Application that the DLL was closed and that I can close the tab where the DLL was?

(Note: whenever I write Form, I mean the DLL's Form.)

This is how I call the DLL from inside the Application:

```
    CallCompany(<Parameters..>,Panel.Handle);
```

And this code below belongs to the DLL:

```
    library Company

    uses
       ...,
       U_Form in 'U_Form.pas' {Form}, Windows,
       ... ;

    {$R *.res}

    procedure CallCompany(<Parameters..>; ParentForm: THandle); export; stdcall;
    var
       ...
    begin

       ... <Preparing the form to open> ...

       Form.Show;

       Windows.SetParent(Form.Handle, ParentForm);
    end;

    exports
       CallCompany;
```

I'm new with DLL's and the way they work. I know I could just not give the user the "Exit" button inside the DLL, forcing him to close the tab, but I wanted to give him that option too.

Ah, and I don't have any code for the OnClose event of the DLL's Form.

If you need any other information in order to help, just tell me and I'll post here whatever is needed.

BTW, I'm using Delphi XE7.

Thanks for the attention.

**Complementing the Question:**

I have a TAdvPageControl, in which I create TAdvTabSheets, and inside this TAdvTabSheets I put a TAdvPanel (set as alClient).

The DLL I call has a Form, does that categorize as "more that a DLL" ?

I'm posting an image so that might clear things a little bit. If it's still confusing, just say it and I'll drop the question.

[image]

Comment: Don't forget that readers read the question and not your mind. *"Whenever I close the tab, ..."* - What tab? Also terminology is a little difficult to follow: *".. opening the DLL in a TAdvPanel .."* You're surely opening something other than a dll.

Comment: Why are you letting the form be closed at all. Just block that and it's all good. Barring the usual provisos relating to UI across DLLs. Oh, and THandle is for kernel handles. A window handle has type HWND. And `export` is ignored, remove it.

Comment: Alright, I'll try to make it more understandable. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: What Sertac says is critical. Terminology is everything. How else can we understand each other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I close the form, the tab where the form was stays open, with no content inside of it.

Don't ever close the form without also closing the tab. That way this situation never arises.

As for specifics, I've got none to offer since the question has no real detail, no MCVE. But it's fairly obvious that the tab and the form that it hosts must be shown and hidden in unison.

Comment: When you mention the form, you mean the DLL's form, right? That's what I want to do, but I don't know when the user closes the form, so I don't know when to close the tab.That's the source of my problem. :/

Comment: Don't let them close the form. Why can they even see a close button? Let them close the tab that hosts the form, but don't let them close the form. When they close the tab, you close the form.

Comment: Okay, I'll do that. Thanks for the help.